# Save InkToolbar options

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, inkcanvas

I need to get and store all the values of an `InkToolbar` in order to retrieve them the next time the user loads the app. These values are: last selected tool, tip dimensions, and color. The problem is that I can't get these values since I didn't find anything about how they're called. Do anyone know how to find them?

Answer (score 0):

For latest selected I have no idea how we can detect it. Maybe you can save all properties when you leave your page. And for color property actually you can use exist propety from related control.

For example, if you add a InkToolbarPencilButton you will be able to use its "SelectedBrush" property to know which RGBA value is selected. Also the "pencilButton.SelectedStrokeWidth" can help you know what's the currently selected strokewidth. If you want to set this when you load your app. You just need to detect the above two properties for a single inktoolbar button.